# C++ std::list with statically allocated nodes

Tags: c++, linux, list

The [Linux linked list](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/list.h) allows for statically allocated nodes to be placed into a list. I would like to do something similar using std::list with a custom allocator.

The beauty of the Linux approach, using static node allocators for embedded systems, is that the number of list nodes allocated can always be maintained as "just enough". There is no pool or heap to allocate from. The list node, if statically allocated, is assigned to the object in use. When needed is used, when not needed is not returned to free or pool (might be wasteful) but is always ready to be used by/for its associated object.

Attempting to do something with std::list I can write a custom allocator but I find that I have only a 'pool' type of construct to work with.

Since the list node (in the ARM GCC 6.x implementation struct _List_node_base found in include/c++/6.3.1/bits/stl_list.h) is implementation dependent (non-portable).

**Is there a known practice for performing static node allocation for std:: containers?**

(I think that if I had a trait std::list::node_type, my problem of cross-functionality would be solved.)

Comment: I'm unsure what you need, just some dedicated memory to be used by the list. Try https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html

Comment: It sounds like you really want an intrusive list. Boost.Intrusive offers utilities to build one.

Comment: The linux linked list embeds the list pointers in the object that are part of the list. This approach is often called "intrusive" , See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/intrusive.html for the C++ counterparts.

Comment: In most cases you should just use a `std::vector`. It will likely perform better.

Comment: Aha! The boost intrusive list is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To work through the usage of the boost::intrusive list I implemented an observer class. Feel free to comment on usage correctness. Hey, the test code works anyway.

Link is here:
https://github.com/natersoz/patterns/tree/master/observer/intrusive_list

Thanks for the pointers to intrusive list.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not mind some extra work regarding list usage, you can have another `std::list`, which would contain all free nodes for certain list type.

You can move nodes to and from that list by using [std::list::splice](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice)

Comment: I think this is it, thanks. I was thinking that a free list might work, but how to avoid the move operation performing a delete/new in between to two operations. This appears to be the solution. Thanks,

Comment: Hmm. This is really close, yet not quite. It still requires a pool allocator in the for of a custom allocator. Providing that each list node owner initializes their list correctly (a requirement in the Linux code as well) and that the pool is correctly sized then all is well. The benefit here is that the allocation size can be checked at run-time initialization. What is still missing is knowing whether the requirements were met at compile time.

Comment: Removed the correct answer here. Boost intrusive list is the best answer.

Comment: @natersoz If nobody else answers, you can write your own answer, explaining solution to your problem, and accept it. That way this QA could help others with the same problem.